# Imprimir variáveis de dois foreach numa tabela em diferentes colunas - codeigniter

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

Estou a tentar imprimir uma tabela que aceda a base de dados e que insira os diferentes valores de cada array em cada coluna. O problema consiste em não imprimir corretamente os valores..

Controller:

```
 private function mostrar_resultados() {

    //vai buscar o resultado da pesquisa
    $query = $this->Oportunidades_model->busca_oportunidade();
    $query1 = $this->Oportunidades_model->busca_funcao();

    //obtem o resultado em forma de array bidimensional
    $data['resultados_pesquisa'] = $query->result_array();
    $data['resultados_funcao']=$query1->result_array();

    //passa as variáveis anteriores para a view
    $this->load->view('verOportunidades', $data);

  }
```

Model:

```
class Oportunidades_model extends CI_Model {
  //fazer echo
  //edita um voluntario;
  function busca_oportunidade()
  {
    $interrogacaoVol_sql = "SELECT id_oport, descricao_oport FROM oportunidade";
    $query = $this->db->query($interrogacaoVol_sql);
    return $query;
  }

  function busca_funcao()
  {
    $interrogacaoVol_sql = "SELECT id_fun, descricao_fun FROM funcao";
    $query = $this->db->query($interrogacaoVol_sql);
    return $query;
  }
}
```

View:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Descricao</th>
    <th>Função</th>
  </tr>

  <?php
  foreach ($resultados_pesquisa as $linha)
  {
    $descricao = $linha["DESCRICAO_OPORT"];

    foreach ($resultados_funcao as $key) {
      $funcao = $key["DESCRICAO_FUN"];
      echo "<tr><td>$descricao</td><td>$funcao</td></tr>";        
    }
  }
  ?>        
</table>
```

Output com 2 oportunidades registadas:

```
 Descricao  Função                          
    teste1      resultado1 
    teste1      resultado2
    teste2      resultado1
    teste2      resultado2
```

Desejado:

```
  Descricao Função                          
    teste1      resultado1 
    teste2      resultado2
```

Comment: Conseguiu ajustar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sup>**NOTA:** estou me atendo ao que você colocou em "desejado" na pergunta. Olhando o resto do seu código, me parece que não está tendo uma maneira segura de se fazer a coluna da esquerda se relacionar com a da direita, mas para resolver isso, não dá só com o que foi perguntado.</sup>

Supondo que `$resultados_pesquisa` e `$resultados_funcao` tenham o mesmo tamanho, basta isso:

```
<?php
   $count = count( $resultados_pesquisa );
   for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ )
   {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.$resultados_pesquisa[$i]['DESCRICAO_OPORT'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$resultados_funcao[$i]['DESCRICAO_FUN'].'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';        
   }
?>
```

Por segurança, pode fazer o `$count` pelo valor com menos dados:

```
   $count = min( count( $resultados_pesquisa ), count( $resultados_funcao) );
```

Se os dados não estiverem em HTML, é fundamental usar `htmlentities`:

```
   echo '<td>'.htmlentities($resultados_pesquisa[$i]['DESCRICAO_OPORT']).'</td>';
```

(mesma coisa para a linha seguinte).

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: Se no caso de não terem o mesmo tamanho como poderia fazer?

Comment: @Rafael tá na resposta, a linha com o "min" faz a tabela pegar o tamanho menor. se precisar do maior e deixar em branco o resto, basta trocar o min por max, e colocar um if para cada echo para não pegar índices inexistentes.